# overflow:scroll not working for div containing table in ie and ff

Tags: css

I have a div which should be a percentage based height. It contains a table, and when the window is too short, the div should have a scrollbar to view the contents of the table. It looks right in Chrome but in IE and FF the minimum height of the div is the height of the table it contains.

Here is a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Xyb/

Here is the html:

```
<div class="outerDiv">
    <table class="outerTable">
        <tr>
            <td class="header">Title
                <table class="innerTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="data">User info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="data">User info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="data">User info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="data">User info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="data">User info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="data">User info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="data">User info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="data">User info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="data">User info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="data">User info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="data">User info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="data">User info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="data">User info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="data">User info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="data">User info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="data">User info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="data">User info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="data">User info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="data">User info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="data">User info</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
 .outerDiv{
   border: thin solid black;
   height:90%;
   overflow:scroll;
 }
```

In response to the the people posting below, even after adding

html,body{
        height:100%;
    }

The div still takes the full height of the table in IE and FF.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem - the height is essentially 90% of the document and the document is happily taller than the window. This solution usually works - setting the document to the height of the window [see it working on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Qn53/):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

 .outerDiv{
    border: thin solid black;
    height: 90%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `css` to set the `hmtl` and `body` tags to consume 100% of the page height in order to reference the viewport of the parent container:

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Updated **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Xyb/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Looks exactly the same in Chrome and FF for me, and rendering as I expect. When you give something a height of 90%, it looks for the height of its parent, so it can work out what height to give it. In your case the parent is the HTML document which has no fixed height, so the browser cannot calculate what 90% of that height is